# How to use Javascript or Jquery to toggle the visibility of a html div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a basic site and I've got the following script that hides a div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('description');">Show/Hide Description</a>

<div id="description">
<br>
<br>
<p>This is a test paragraph</p>
</div>
```

When I load the page, the default is that the text is shown. How can I hide the text inside the div each time the page is loaded?

I want the user to manually click the button to view the text.

EDIT:

I've now added a picture of a + symbol, so that a user can click the + and the text appears by using the following lines:

```
  <h4>Backstory</h4> 

  <img alt="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" src="./images/headerExpand.png" a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('backstory');">Show/Hide Description</a>

<div id="backstory" style="display: none">
<br>
   <p>This is a new block of text</p>
</div>
```

The ./images/headerExpand.png is the icon of the + symbol

How would I change the + icon to a - icon once the + icon has been clicked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the display to none

```
<div id="description" style="display: none">
```

---

A redesigned solution might look like

```
<!-- Add a class toggler and the id of the target element as the href-->
<a href="#description" class="toggler">Show/Hide Description</a>

<!-- Add a class hidden so that the element is hidden when the page loads -->
<div id="description" class="hidden">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

then jQuery script

```
// dom ready handler
jQuery(function () {
    //register a click handelr for all anchor elements with class toggler
    $('a.toggler').click(function (e) {
        //prevent the default action of the event
        e.preventDefault();
        //togger the visibility of the element targetted by the href
        $($(this).attr('href')).toggle()
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Na56D/)

Comment: Thank you that works great. I've added a bit more to my original question. I have a + symbol icon, so now when I click it, my text appears. That's great, but the + icon stays there. How can I make the icon change to a - icon? Thanks again.

Comment: Added at the bottom of original question. Here is the actual line: 

<img alt="" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" src="./images/headerExpand.png" a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('backstory');">Show/Hide Description</a>

Answer (score 1):

use symply CSS :

```
<p style="display:none;">This is a test paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options , set the css property right in the html like the other answers

```
<div id="description" style="display: none">
```

or wrap your javascript in something to tell the page to run the stript on page load

using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //your code
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
  //your code
});
```

or regular old javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
  //your code
});
```